# Sitecore Password setting configuration

Tags: configuration, security

We are on 6.3.1 rev. 110112 and We have some specific requirements for setting up the password in Sitecore from the client side.

For Example, we have the following requirements for the password setting.

One numeric character with upper-case and not to match any of the old password (like should match for last 5 passwords) or to change after certain days like 30 days, restrict a user to change password only a few times in one day etc.

Do we have any specific way to achieve this? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

We had a similar situation a long time back.

You can set apply the strict password limitation using PasswordStrengthRegularExpression property. You should review this
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlmembershipprovider.aspx

As with your requirements, you will need to extend the functionality of the standard membership provider. Just override a few methods such as "CreateUser", "ValidateUser" or "ChangePassword" etc and replace  provider in web.config with a new one

Such requirements as "change every X days" also can be achieved with the help of some scheduled task, which will change the old password and inform the user about a new one etc.

Comment: Thanks, it does provide me the solution and will try to work out on this. Thanks for providing an answer to a complex problem. thank you, Rohit.